# Elastic search filter query with bool returns invalid results

Tags: php, laravel-4, elasticsearch

I'm using Elastic search in Laravel.

So I have query that returns correct result:

```
$results = Es::search(array(
    'index' => 'testindex',
    'type' => $type,
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'filtered' => [
                'query' => [
                    'match' => [
                        '_all' => '2015-02'
                    ]
                ],
                'filter' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                            'term' => [
                                'type' => 11
                            ]
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'size' => 5,
        'from' => 0
    ]
));
```

What it does is:

- searches for $query in all fields AND
- field "type" must be 11.

Here is output: http://pastebin.com/icWniix4
Total 9 results which is correct.

But when I add another must term then it returns invalid results

```
$results = Es::search(array(
    'index' => 'testindex',
    'type' => $type,
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'filtered' => [
                'query' => [
                    'match' => [
                        '_all' => '2015-02'
                    ]
                ],
                'filter' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'must' => [
                            'term' => [
                                'type' => 11
                            ],
                            'term' => [
                                'public' => 1
                            ]
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'size' => 5,
        'from' => 0
    ]
));
```

So this only add term for "public".
What it does is:

- searches for $query in all fields AND
- field "type" must be 11 AND
- field "public" must be 1

So now results are in total 429. It ignores "type" term and returns everything with "public" = 1. But as per docs if I use MUST then it should match all of them. Search result http://pastebin.com/cVcatcyi

So how can I write query that I need? $query + type + public

Official doc's fail to answer my questions.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your trouble spot:

```
                    'must' => [
                        'term' => [
                            'type' => 11
                        ],
                        'term' => [
                            'public' => 1
                        ]
                    ]
```

Here, you're assigning the value of `must` as an associative array that has only one distinct key - `term` actually gets assigned twice, so presumably only one of the assignments will "survive" (presumably `public` survives because it appears last in the definition).  The end result is that `must` ends up pointing at an associative array with only one key-value pair.

What I suspect you have to do is this:

```
                    'must' => [
                        [
                            'term' => [
                                'type' => 11
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            'term' => [
                                'public' => 1
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
```

Now `must` is actually pointing at an array with two items.

Comment: Thanks. Now I feed dumb for missing that.